# Erro no projeto após adicionar dependência do IReport

Tags: maven, ireport

Quando adiciono a seguinte de dependência o projeto e o pom.xml ficam com erro:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Erro:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type ArtifactDescriptorException:
>   Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:5.1.2:
>   ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer
>   net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:pom:5.1.2 from
>   http://repository.primefaces.org was cached in the local repository,
>   resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of
>   prime-repo has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could
>   not transfer artifact net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:pom:5.1.2
>   from/to prime-repo (http://repository.primefaces.org): connect timed
>   out   pom.xml /SistemaSuspensao   line 1  Maven Dependency Problem

E não é só isso, todas as outras dependências ficam com erro também:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei várias versões da biblioteca e o erro persiste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O arquivo não existe no repositório. Pelo menos eu não o encontrei. Por isso o erro.

Pode ser que o repositório esteja errado, ou algum problema no repositório em sí.

Uma solução seria adicionar o .jar manualmente à pasta .m2 (se estiver usando Linux) e ao contêiner de aplicação, além de alterar o `<scope>` para `provided`.

Ou caso o problema esteja no repositório, aguardar que o corrijam e então tentar novamente.

Comment: Entendi, estou com Windows, acho que vou ter que esperar a correção, obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Comment: @Techies no Windows deve ser possível também adicionar manualmente o arquivo ao repositório do maven, mas eu não tenho conhecimento para indicar os passos. Talvez esta página te ajude em algo: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/5.1.2

Comment: @Techies encontrei esta pergunta do SO em inglês que pode ser a resolução do problema: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16719901/what-are-the-dependecy-need-to-be-added-for-jasperreport-5-0-1

Comment: Já tinha visto essa pergunta e não resolveu também, creio que o repositório deles está com problema mesmo. Vou tentar colocar manualmente. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

O erro é devido ao maven não ter conseguido resolver a dependência em nenhum dos repositórios configurados, tanto dos repositórios que são padrão, quando do que você explicitou em suas configurações (no caso do *Primefaces*).

Ao invés de incluir manualmente a dependência no seu repositório local (por padrão encontrado em `.m2` no diretório do usuário) você pode adicionar um repositório que possui tal dependência, já que existe repositório online e público que a possui.

O repositório da sonatype (bastante usado, inclusive) possui a dependência que você precisa. Então, para resolver a dependência por ele, basta adicionar algo como isto ao seu `pom.xml`:

```xml
<repository>
    <id>sonatype-releases</id>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
</repository>
```

E depois disto conseguirá resolvê-la, da forma com que declarou ou removendo o escopo `compile` que é padrão, podendo ficar assim:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

A abordagem de dizer que dependências que por natureza não se apresentam com escopo `provided` deve ser evitada ([veja o signifado de cada escopo](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope)), uma vez que é grande a chance de acontecer erros.

---

Abaixo está um exemplo completo de `pom.xml` utilizando a configuração conforme dito:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.brunocesar</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasper-dependency</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-releases</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Este é o log de download das dependências:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building jasper-dependency 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/net/sf/jasperreports/jasperreports/5.1.2/jasperreports-5.1.2.pom
Downloaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/net/sf/jasperreports/jasperreports/5.1.2/jasperreports-5.1.2.pom (13 KB at 7.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/net/sf/jasperreports/jasperreports/5.1.2/jasperreports-5.1.2.jar
Downloaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/net/sf/jasperreports/jasperreports/5.1.2/jasperreports-5.1.2.jar (4428 KB at 402.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ jasper-dependency ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ jasper-dependency ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 15.988 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-07T10:51:48-03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/183M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Como pode perceber o download foi feito do repositório citado e configurado. Como no seu caso deu errado, algumas possíveis causas são:

- repositório configurado errado;
- cache no repositório local do maven, force a atualização usando `mvn clean compile -U` ou algum outro *lifecycle*

Comment: Já tinha feito manualmente, mas tentei fazer conforme sua resposta e o erro continua.

Comment: @Techies atualizei a resposta com um exemplo completo de uso, assim como o log de uso.

Comment: E mesmo assim ainda aparece o erro de `missing artifact`

Comment: @Techies ok, deve ser algum outro problema no seu projeto, valeu :)

Comment: Entendi, obrigado pela ajuda. Testei em outros projetos e também não deu. Acho que as vezes possa ser alguma configuração